# How to return a function from a method by naming it when there is more than one exists?

Tags: scala

I am trying to return a function from a method in java.sql.PreparedStatement by doing this:

```
def getSetDateFunction(stmt:PreparedStatement)={
  stmt.setDate _
}
```

this fails with

```
ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
[error] both method setDate in trait PreparedStatement of type (x$1: Int, x$2: java.sql.Date, x$3: java.util.Calendar)Unit
[error] and  method setDate in trait PreparedStatement of type (x$1: Int, x$2: java.sql.Date)Unit
[error] match expected type ?
[error]     stmt.setDate _
[error]          ^
[error] one error found
```

Is there a way to hint which one of the methods I want to return?

Comment: This is one of the main arguments for avoiding overloading—eta expansion just isn't going to work for you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hint wich one to return by specifying return type of getSetDateFunction:

```
def getSetDateFunction(stmt:PreparedStatement):(Int,java.sql.Date)=>Unit = {
   stmt.setDate _
}
```

is going to return second function

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can specify the function by explicitly providing the number and the types of its arguments.

Assuming you want the one that takes two arguments:

```
def getSetDateFunction(stmt: PreparedStatement): (Int, java.sql.Date) => Unit =
  stmt.setDate
```

Or:

```
def getSetDateFunction(stmt: PreparedStatement) =
  stmt.setDate(_: Int, _: java.sql.Date)
```